# file "(...).csv" not Stata file error in using merge command

Tags: csv, merge, stata, using, dta

I use Stata 12.

I want to add some country code identifiers from file `df_all_cities.csv` onto my working data.

However, this line of code:

```
merge 1:1 city country using "df_all_cities.csv", nogen keep(1 3)
```

Gives me the error:

```
. run "/var/folders/jg/k6r503pd64bf15kcf394w5mr0000gn/T//SD44694.000000"
file df_all_cities.csv not Stata format
r(610);
```

This is an attempted solution to my previous problem of the file being a dta file not working on this version of Stata, so I used R to convert it to .csv, but that also doesn't work. I assume it's because the command itself "using" doesn't work with csv files, but how would I write it instead?

Comment: `merge` will only accept .dta files. "not working with this version of Stata" means, perhaps,  that your version is older than that of the .dta file you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right. The command `merge` cannot read a `.csv` file directly. (`using` is technically not a command here, it is a common syntax tag indicating a file path follows.)

You need to read the `.csv` file with the command `insheet`. You can use it like this.

```
* Preserve saves a snapshot of your data which is brought back at "restore"
preserve 
    
    * Read the csv file. clear can safely be used as data is preserved
    insheet using "df_all_cities.csv", clear
    
    * Create a tempfile where the data can be saved in .dta format
    tempfile country_codes
    save `country_codes'

* Bring back into working memory the snapshot saved at "preserve"
restore

* Merge your country codes from the tempfile to the data now back in working memory
merge 1:1 city country using `country_codes', nogen keep(1 3)
```

See how `insheet` is also using `using` and this command accepts `.csv` files.

Comment: `insheet` should work but has been superseded by `import delimited` as from Stata 13.

Comment: Ah, I write commands targeting Stata 12 so maybe an old habit. OP seems to use an older version of Stata, so I will keep `insheet` in my answer. But good point.

Comment: Absolutely.  `insheet` is a better guess at what the OP needs.

Comment: Indeed I use Stata 12 :)

Comment: @TheIceBear I got an error saying "variable city not found
r(111);". Both the working file and the df_all_cities.csv has a column called "city" though.

Comment: Either one of the file don't or the csv file was not imported properly. Did you check the result after `insheet using "df_all_cities.csv", clear`. If it does not work as intended, see the helpfile. My guess is that you need the option `names`. My solution only addresses your original question about `merge` not accepting `.csv` files directly.

Comment: @TheIceBear you're right, indeed the column names are on row 1 and are called v1, v2 and v3

Comment: @TheIceBear sorry to bother you, but now I added "names" in insheet using "df_all_cities.csv", names, clear. But it says "you must start with an empty dataset
r(18);" now at the insheet line. I tried clearing first.

Comment: If you type `help insheet` in Stata you find the help file for `insheet`. At the bottom you can see examples. there you can see that when using two options - for example `insheet using auto.raw, clear double` - you do not put a comma in-between each option. You seem to have a comma in-between `names` and `clear`.

Comment: That solved it!