# File not found when appending a csv file

Tags: csv, import, append, stata

Stata version: 12.1

I get an error "file not found" using this code:

```
cd "$path_in"
insheet using "df_mcd_clean.csv", comma clear
    append using "df_mcd15_clean.csv" #where error happens
    append using "df_ingram_liu1998_clean.csv" 
    append using "df_wccd_clean.csv"
```

I double checked that the file is indeed called that and located in the directory.

Comment: See detailed solution to similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958836/file-csv-not-stata-file-error-in-using-merge-command/70961450#70961450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` is for appending .dta files. Therefore, if you ask to append `foo.csv` Stata assumes you are referring to `foo.csv.dta`, which it can't find.

The solutions include

1. Combine the .csv files outside Stata.
2. Read in each .csv file, `save` as .dta, then `append`.

The current version of the help for `append` says this:

> `append` appends Stata-format datasets stored on disk to the end of the dataset in memory.  If any filename is
> specified without an extension, `.dta` is assumed.

and that was true too in Stata 12. (Whether the wording was identical, you can say.)

Comment: My stata version doesn't accept dta files unfortunately. When I try to use one, it says it's an invalid format. That's why I converted it to csv. Is not not possible to use append in any way with a csv?

Comment: If that's true, your version of Stata is badly broken. What you mean, I imagine, is more specific: your version of  Stata can't read in .dta files created with a later specification.  What I said is absolute: `append` won't accept .csv files, as you found, and route #2 is the main answer for you.

Comment: Then it's probably dta files from a newer version. I will try to reconvert.

Comment: If `sysuse auto` works in your Stata, it can read .dta files.